# PKCS12 file can't load by keytool

Tags: java, certificate

Get a p12 file , tried to load by keytool, but it shows 0 entry ,But  it can be import  by Microsoft windows application,  as simply double click the file

```
 Keytool -list -v -keystore test.p12 -storetype PKCS12
 Enter keystore password:

 Keystore type: PKCS12
 Keystore provider: IBMJCE

 Your keystore contains 0 entry
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very stupid error which comes where there is a space after the entry in the file. There are many more scenarios, where this occurs like in Websphere when you are trying to load this file in the keystore and there is already a file, then sometimes it throws teh same error.

I would suggest you to open this file in the most basic word editor, like windows notepad or command line editors and check if there is any space or extra character at the end.

Comment: thanks,but what do you mean extra character or space at the end? I am viewing in hex mode , do you mean 0x00 or 0x20 ?

Comment: I mean .. a line or spaces.

Comment: Hi Jammy Lee, were you able to find a solution for this? PKCS12 is not a plain text format, so I doubt editing it and removing spaces is advisable